# Filtering out illegal moves from a map of available moves

Tags: clojure

I'm writing a console blackjack game.

To hold all the possible moves a player can make, I have a map that maps a keyboard key to a move keyword:

```
(def move-map {\s :stand
               \h :hit
               \p :split
               \d :double})
```

Splitting and doubling are only available options during the first move though, so I'd like to filter them out of the available moves before verifying the user's input if they aren't legal moves.

My current method is to indicate which are legal using a flag for doubling and one for splitting, then filtering the map if a flag isn't set:

```
(defn- filter-moves [moves can-split? can-double?]
  (let [r-split (if can-split? moves (filter #(not= :split (second %)) moves))
        r-doub (if can-double? r-split (filter #(not= :double (second %)) r-split))]
    (into {} r-doub)))
```

The problem is, this contains a fair amount of redundancy. It should only iterate the map once because `filter` is lazy, but I'm still not happy with this solution.

Usage:

```
(filter-moves move-map true false)

=> {"s" :stand, "h" :hit, "p" :split}
```

Any improvement suggestions would be appreciated. I'm not against redesigning the function if it helps readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate once by using `remove` in combination with a set of illegal moves:

```
(defn- filter-moves [moves can-split? can-double?]
  (let [illegal? (cond-> #{} 
                   (not can-split?) (conj :split)
                   (not can-double?) (conj :double))]
    (into {} (remove #(illegal? (second %)) moves))))
```

What's more, If I understand correctly that `moves` is the map mapping keys to moves. In my opinion, this map has no place in your core game logic: have your `filter-moves` function manipulate only sets of moves and keep any notion of user input at the edge of your system.

Comment: Cool. Never used `cond->` before. And I know tying key bindings directly to the set of legal moves is a bad idea. It was kind of a hack to get a test up and running quickly, but ya, bad idea. Thanks.